# How to input a loop value in the command line program?

Tags: python, shell

Suppose I have a program that runs in the `zsh`.

It accepts some command, say type `i` + `number` and `Enter` key means insert a number in something like data structure and wait for the next input.

I need to type so much number to test the bug, which is time consuming.
So I want to write a shell script to create a loop that can do it automatically. I have already checked some documents, yet didn't find the right way to run the script in the program prompt.

I mean now that the program already runs and waits for the command I defined, how can I manipulate the input in the terminal by using script?

p.s.
My English is not that good, so my description maybe kinda misleading:(, Kind Stack Overflowers, Can anyone offer help?

Python has `os` module, I tried and failed.

I don't want to write the loop directly in the program code.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: How about `python your_script.py < your_input.txt`?

Comment: @KlausD. Oh forget the `<` operator, It works you can make it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this must be what you are trying to accomplish:

```
how_many = int(input('How many numbers do you want to append to the list? '))
a_list = []

for i in range(how_many):
    number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    a_list.append(number)

print("The list is: {}".format(a_list))
```

In your shell, you could run it like so:

```
> python .\test.py
How many numbers do you want to append to the list? 2
Enter a number: 10
Enter a number: 20
The list is: [10, 20]
```

If you want to get input from a file, you could try something like this:

```
import sys

in_file = sys.argv[1]    
a_list = []

with open(in_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        print("The numbers in the line: {}".format(line))        
        numbers = line.split(',')
        for num in numbers:
            a_list.append(int(num.strip()))

print("Done appending the numbers to the list.")
print("The list is: {}".format(a_list))
```

Trying it in the shell:

```
> python test.py nums.txt
The numbers in the line: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Done appending the numbers to the list.
The list is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The `nums.txt` file has this one line: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`